# Dynamic scripts loading

Tags: javascript

I have a web application and i need to load many `js` scripts after page loading. I'm trying to do it in `while` loop, like this:

```
while (....) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  //
  // Here i'm adding script to the html page
  //

  script.onload = function(){
    //
    // Do somthing here
    //
  }

}
```

But i have a problem, i have 3 - 5 `js` scripts in different time, but correctly loads only one script, other scripts or not have a time for loading in loop or i do not understand what's wrong. How to correctly load and include to `html` page many `js` scripts?

Thank you.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it...

Comment: If you obfuscate an essential parts, nobody can help with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably take a look [at this blog](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/essential-javascript-top-five-script-loaders-8122862) it explains different JS Loaders... Currently I'm using HeadJS (moved away from RequireJS) and so far it's been really good.

I even have a Loader.js class that is the only script I'm loading on my HTML code (besides the head.js itself) and works like a charm.

See the code below :

```
head.js("./js/ink/ink-all.js", 
        "./js/jquery/jquery.js", 
        "./js/html5-boilerplate/plugins.js", 
        "./js/i18next/i18next-1.6.3.js", 
        "./js/reclameAqui/ReclameAqui.js", 
        "./js/reclameAqui/controller/IndexController.js", 
        "./js/reclameAqui/controller/NavBarController.js", 
        "./js/reclameAqui/controller/FooterController.js", 
        "./js/reclameAqui/controller/ApplicationController.js", 
        "./js/angular/angular.js", 
        "./js/reclameAqui/utils/i18n/DictionaryLoader.js", 
        function() {
          var appReclameAqui;
          console.info("Loading...");
          return appReclameAqui = new ReclameAqui();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. I'm using [].forEach instead `while` loop.